# Equality of sums in the context of discrete Fourier analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, integers

I'm in the context of discrete Fourier analysis and, in particular, trigonometric polynomial interpolation.

I cannot understand how to prove the following equality:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\hat f(-N/2+\ell N)e^{-iN/2x}+ \hat f(N/2+\ell N)e^{iN/2x}\right)+ \sum_{|k|<N/2}\sum_{\ell\neq 0} \hat f (k+\ell N)e^{ikx}\\
 =\frac{1}{2}\left(\hat f(-N/2)e^{-iN/2x}+ \hat f(N/2 )e^{iN/2x}\right)+
\sum_{|m|>N/2}\hat f(m)e^{imx},
$$
where $N\in\mathbb Z$ has been fixed and $\ell$ varies in $\mathbb Z$. Somehow it makes sense since for every fixed $\ell\neq 0$, it holds $|k+\ell N|>N/2$. however I cannot conclude. Any help?

Comment: @JeanMarie $\hat f (m)$ denotes the (complex) $m$-th coefficient of the Fourier series of $f$

Comment: Therefore, the RHS is the truncated Fourier series (deprived of certain "central terms"). **There is a problem :** If we take $N=1$, the RHS is equal to $f(x)-f(0)$ whereas the LHS is equal to $\sum_{\ell\neq 0} \hat f (0+\ell )e^{0x}=f(0)$ !?

Comment: @JeanMarie I'll edit the question

Comment: You have added "trigonometric polynomials" ; it means that the sums are finite, right ?

Comment: No, I added it because this is part of a proof related to trigonometric interpolation. Sums are not finite

Comment: I wouldn't be surprized that this formula is an avatar of [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) but I don't see how.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. Then it's not so straightforward...

Comment: You equality still looks strange to me for $x=0$; Is $x=0$ a discontinuity point of the Fourier series ? I mean by that : is $f(0)=f(2 \pi)$ or not ?